# What does GitHub for Windows' "sync" do?

Tags: git, github-for-windows

With GitHub for Windows, you can "publish" a branch, and then "sync" that branch to GitHub.

[image]

Is the sync basically a `git pull` and `git push`? Or is there more to it? If I wanted to do the exact same steps as "sync" from the command line, what should I do?

(It's not Open Source, or I'd just read that.)

Answer (score 53):

Sync does `git pull --rebase` and then if there are local changes, it does `git push`.

From here: http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx#87318

Comment: What happens if there is a conflict during the rebase step?

Comment: @Svante it just fails, and offers to open a shell for you to sort the mess out. Which is how I got to this page :-)

Comment: Is this still true?  I just did a sync and ended up with a merge commit, which should never happen if the flow is: git pull --rebase; git push

Comment: Any explanation for @Michas Caldwell's comment, I believe he is right?

Comment: Can confirm hitting _Sync_ just now did a `git pull` rather than a `git pull --rebase`, thus creating an additional _Merge branch 'master' of ..._ commit.

Comment: What is a re-base?

Answer (score 45):

Since the above answer was more than two years ago, an updated answer to this question is: due to some bugs with *rebase*, the "sync" button does not do `git pull --rebase` anymore. Instead, it does **`git pull`** which will do **merge** if there are conflicts, according to this [release notes](https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html) (see release 1.3.0).

The link above is not available at this time. Here is [the new release notes](https://desktop.github.com/release-notes/windows/).

Comment: Actually, that's not completely true. ONLY if a rebase doesn't work, it tries to do a merge.

Comment: The release notes link is broken.

Comment: @JorisMeys I'm not sure your statement is true. In my experience, if there are *any* commits ahead of mine on remote, it will create a merge commit, even when it could do a rebase.

Comment: @JeradRose When I wrote my comment we were at Github Desktop v. 2.x, and we're at 3.3 by now :-) But you're right, I've noticed the same.

Answer (score 17):

"Sync" would be any actions necessary to have your local branch match your remote branch. If your local branch had commits that your remote branch didn't, then "sync" would push your branch. If the remote branch was ahead of your local branch, then "sync" would pull first (specifically, `git pull --rebase`, as was [explained](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/05/21/introducing-github-for-windows.aspx#87318) by Phil Haack). "Sync" is just a shortcut to getting the local and remote to mirror each other.

From the [GitHub site](http://windows.github.com/):

`The sync button turns the complex workflow of pulling and pushing into a single operation. It notifies you when there are new changes to pull down and lets you quickly share local changes.`

Comment: It doesn't just pull - it does "git pull --rebase", which is a crucial difference. Also, the order you have is wrong, pull before push.

Comment: @Andiih My language was generalized and not an ordered list of operations. The order was implied - notice I say "if the remote branch **was** ahead of your local branch"? My description was also a direct quote from the GitHub site. Regardless, Matt Rix's answer is more detailed, and deserves to be marked as the answer. I've made some small edits to clarify any confusion in my answer.

Comment: Does github sync also fetch upstream changes, in addition to origin.  I.e. I haved f9rked a repo, and have a local clone of the fork, what I really want is the changes from upstream, not just origin

Comment: @AaronLS GitHub for Windows is only built to work with one remote right now, namely `origin`. To work with multiple remotes, you'll have to use the command line. Relevant info can be found [here](http://windows.github.com/help.html), under "Multiple Git remotes & non-GitHub remotes".

Answer (score 4):

To add to @ethanyang's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27201187/2899995),

According to the alias configured in the gitconfig,

```
[alias]
...
sync = !git pull && git push
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does the ! mean in the above line?

Comment: @ScottRomack it means that it's treated as a shell command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083933/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-git-config-alias

Comment: Does GitHub Desktop have this alias already setup? If so, where is this config located? I didn't see this alias in my global `.gitconfig`. Or is this just an override of your own?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "syncing" is timestamp ID-ed.  Cause if I use more than one local machine to code the same project, my remote repo will always pull the latest timestamped codes or push the latest timestamped codes to all my local machines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35000259)