# What does the exclamation mark mean in git config alias?

Tags: git

I just see a git config command as below:

```
git config --global alias.out \!"git fetch; git cherry origin/HEAD -v"
```

what does it mean? Is it equal to this:

```
git config --global alias.out '!git fetch; git cherry origin/HEAD -v',
```

I am confused with the exclamation mark,any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I thought the exclamation mark meant that the alias is a shell command, rather than a git command. I can't remember 100%, though.

Comment: Note that if you alias a command like `lg1 = log --graph --format...` you can't alias _that_ as though it's a subcommand (`lg = lg1` will not work), but you need to use `!` as in `lg = !"git lg1"`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

From the [git-config manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> If the alias expansion is prefixed with an exclamation point, it will be treated as a shell 
>   command.

Comment: “Note that shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.” → useful, i.e. for (example) `git config --global alias.conf "!cat .git/config"`

Answer (score 9):

The [most-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084052/4561887) says only that the `!` makes the git alias a "shell command". So...what does that mean!? That simply begs my immediate follow-up question:

> What does executing a git alias as a "shell command" mean and do?

@Frank Nocke graciously answers that question [in his comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083933/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean-in-git-config-alias#comment72607455_21084052). His comment really should be another answer (so I could have upvoted it), so here is my attempt at making it an answer:

Let's quote some more of the manual from `man git commit` (my emphasis added):

> If the alias expansion is **prefixed with an exclamation point**, it will be **treated as a shell command**. For example, defining `alias.new = !gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`, the invocation `git new` is equivalent to running the shell command `gitk --all --not ORIG_HEAD`. Note that **shell commands will be executed from the top-level directory of a repository, which may not necessarily be the current directory.**  `GIT_PREFIX` is set as returned by running `git rev-parse --show-prefix` from the original current directory. See `git-rev-parse(1)`.

See also (thank you [@Martin C. for pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298960/git-add-and-commit-in-one-command/4299159?noredirect=1#comment125771833_4299159)!): https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases, which says (emphasis added):

> As you can tell, Git simply replaces the new command with whatever you alias it for. However, maybe you want to **run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand.** In that case, you start the command with a `!` character. **This is useful if you write your own tools that work with a Git repository.** We can demonstrate by aliasing git visual to run `gitk`:
>
> ```
> $ git config --global alias.visual '!gitk'
> ```

**So, the `!` indicates that the git alias is accessing a regular shell command instead of a *git subcommand*, and it also causes git to execute this shell command *in the root directory of the git repository* instead of in the directory you are currently in.**

So, if you run this command to give you a git alias to `git add` and `git commit` in one `git add-commit` command ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299159/4561887)):

```sh
git config --global alias.add-commit '!git add -A && git commit'
```

...then you'll get this in your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```sh
[alias]
    add-commit = !git add -A && git commit
```

Now you can use that alias like this:

```sh
git add-commit -m 'My commit message'
```

And that alias is run as though it was a regular shell command run at the root dir of the git repo, so it's kind of like doing this apparently:

```sh
starting_dir="$PWD"
# see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/4561887
repo_root_dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
cd "$repo_root_dir"
git add -A && git commit -m 'My commit message'
cd "$starting_dir"
```

So, if you're not a big fan of git aliases, and just want to make it a bash function instead, you could do that by adding the following to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file instead:

```sh
git-add-commit() {
    starting_dir="$PWD"
    # See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/4561887
    repo_root_dir="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
    cd "$repo_root_dir"
    git add -A
    git commit "$@"
    cd "starting_dir"
}
```

Then run it like this (notice the extra dash after `git`):

```sh
git-add-commit -m 'My commit message'
```

OR, make that a stand-alone executable bash script in a file called `git-add-commit` inside a folder in your `PATH` (such as at `~/bin/git-add-commit`), and with the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` shebang line at the top, and then you can run the command the same as the git alias, withOUT the hyphen after "git", like this:

```sh
git add-commit -m 'My commit message'
```

This works because the `git` executable apparently scans all directories in your `PATH` variable for all executables named `git-ANYTHING` and allows them to be run as `git ANYTHING`.

### See also:

1. [Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957978/4561887)
2. [Git add and commit in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4299159/4561887)
3. *****https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: An excellent and exhaustive answer to a seemingly obscure and concealed feature of git which provides a high level rundown of the feature and consequently demystifies it as a simple shell script. Perfectly complete and relevant. Every git user should read this after a year of git usage.

Answer (score 5):

From https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

> However, maybe you want to run an external command, rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with a ! character

So if you only want to use git **subcommand**, you don't need to use ! here.

But if you want to use git command/external command, then you need !.