# Sync Branch and staying up to date with a project using GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github-for-windows

What do I need to do in the GitHub for Windows app to stay up to date with changes made to a project or repository hosted on GitHub?

I will most likely not be editing, but do want to stay aware of and incorporate the changes that are made to the project.

When I clone in desktop, using the GitHub for Windows GUI, one of the options I have is "Sync Branch", which is defined as "sharing your local commits on the server and pulling down changes from others".  With whom am I sharing my local commits? Is it the origin source? And, whose changes am I "pulling down"?

It seems like the "sync branch" option in the GUI would do both (whether I want to or not).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104513/what-does-github-for-windows-sync-do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can fork the repo (even if you don't intend to contribute back), if only to keep a clear link with the original upstream repo.

From there, you can:

- clone your fork locally
- add a remote referring to the upstream original repo

  ```
  git remote add upstream https://github.com/User/repo
  ```
- set the upstream branch to the remote 'upstream'.
  That way, a simple `git pull` will **always pull from the original repo** (the `upstream` one)

  ```
  git checkout master
  git branch -u upstream/master
  ```
- set `push.default` to `matching`.
  That way, a `git push origin` will push all your local branches (updated from upstream) to your fork.

  ```
  git config push.default matching
  ```

The idea behind those settings is: **pulling from upstream, but pushing to origin**, meaning **keep track of the new changes**: you record in your fork the last SHA1 you pulled from upstream.

That way, you can **from any workstation**:

- `pull` from `origin` (to update your local clone to the last SHA1 you memorized in your fork),
- and `pull` from `upstream` in order to check/see any new commits from said original repo.