# Why does GitHub desktop present history as if it was from only one of our team?

Tags: github-desktop

I'm using Git in a team of three to build an iOS app. For this project we are all Mac and Xcode based and have a variety of different ways of using Git: within Xcode, using Github Desktop, and from the Bash terminal.

I am confused about the history I am seeing in GitHub desktop - it is linear and appears to be all from one developer.

I can use the terminal command `git log --since='2016-05-06' --pretty=format:"%h %an %cd" --graph` to see the last few days' commits:

[image: terminal git log screenshot]

I can clearly see that the last twelve commits are spread between all three contributors. But it does not look like this in GitDesktop:

[image: GitHub screenshot]

Here all the recent commits seem to be from one developer, and all laid out linearly without the branching structure shown by the `--graph` option to `git log`.

Why is GitHub desktop presenting the history as one developer? Where is the branching structure gone? How do I get GitHub Desktop to show me the history that `git log` is able to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I heard back from the GitHub team.

The terminal command that is a better comparison is `git log --since='2016-05-06' --pretty=format:"%h %an %cd" --graph --first-parent`. Looking at the `git log` [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) the `--first-parent` option is described as:

> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This
>   option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a 
>   particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be 
>   only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this 
>   option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your 
>   history by such a merge.

In their reply GitHub share what one of their developers said about the GitHub Desktop [Comparison Graph](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/about-the-comparison-graph/)

> "GitHub Desktop is optimized for [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/). In this model, merges 
>   almost always represent either (1) a branch getting merged into the
>   default branch via a pull request or (2) a branch being updated from
>   the default branch.
>
> In the first case, it's most useful to see which pull requests have
>   been merged—not the individual commits that make up that pull request.
>   We think pull requests are amazing and very useful for understanding
>   history, so we want to prioritize them.
>
> In the second case, seeing the commits that came in with a merge only
>   obscures the changes on the branch. It's most useful to see the
>   commits that are unique to the branch."

But the goal is that "in the future [they] would like to make all commits reachable in GitHub Desktop"