# What does GitHub for Windows/Mac “publish” do?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows, github-for-mac

Like in [What does GitHub for Windows' "sync" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104513/what-does-github-for-windows-sync-do)

What does GitHub for Windows/Mac “publish” do?

Does it push the branch to my origin?

[image: Publish]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it push the branch to my origin?

Yes, but if you don't have an origin yet, it will ask you for the kind of remote repo you want to create.
(create... on GitHub of course)

See "[Push your code to GitHub.com](https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/)"

> Click the “`Publish`” button in the upper-right corner and GitHub Desktop will ask you what kind of repository to create:
>
> - **Public repository** — Anyone can see a public repository, but you choose who can commit (make changes) to it. You can create as many public repositories as you want on GitHub.com for free.
> - **Private repository** — By default, only you can see a private repository. You choose who can see and commit to this repository by adding collaborators. Private repositories require a paid subscription on GitHub.com.

Then the button transforms to a "`Sync`" button.

Comment: Yes, Sync comes when the local branch is already mapped to a remote branch for push purpose, generally origin. Publish comes when we dont have the mapping and GitHub desktop means to Publish the same branch to origin. Sometimes, I also do one mistake and end up here. In the middle of a big rebase, after merging files, sometimes I forget to do `git rebase --continue` and then when i go to GitHub desktop tool, it shows me Publish and I become confused. This is because for rebase, the pointer moves to a temp branch. Just sharing if someone is in confusionl