# New Repository From WampServer WWW Folder Not Publishing Completely

Tags: github, github-for-windows

I am using GitHub Desktop 0.7.0 on top of Windows 10 and trying to publish a WampServer project as a GitHub repository but after publishing the repository I am not seeing any including Files in neither Desktop GitHub or on my `github.com`.

Here is the steps I took to publish a repository called `MapApp` which is basically a simple website application.

1- I tried to add anew repository from GitHub Desktop File-> `Add Local Repository...` option.

[image]

[image]

2- Navaigated to the WampServer **WWW** folder

[image]

3- After Selecting `MapApp` Folder this dialog puped up

[image]

4- I clicked on `Create A repository` and this dialog box appeared

[image]

5- I just typed the Name of repository as `MapApp` and clicked on `create repository`and eventually I published the repository

[image]

**But** in both side of repository (Desktop Application/ Web) I am not seeing any of including files and folders!
[image]

Here are the output of the Desktop and web views

[image]

[image]

sorry for taking too long but I tried to illustrated exactly what I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating and publishing are not enough to see the files published as well.

You need to add and commit them locally, before publishing (again) your repo (no need to re-create it though)

See "[Committing and reviewing changes to your project](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/committing-and-reviewing-changes-to-your-project/)"

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/desktop/commit-all-win.png]

And:

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/desktop/commit-button-win.png]

In command-line, you can:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Then either publish, or `git push`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Vonc, but I am a little bit confused here. According to what you recommend on `You need to add and commit them locally` I am not seeing any Add functionality on Desktop Github! Can you please let me know how to do that?

Comment: @JJBOBO Whenever a GUI does not show what you expect, switch first to command-line. Try a git status. You will have a clearer view of the situation that way.

Comment: @JJBOBO Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582467/6309 for seeing the publish button.

Comment: Thanks it is working now but only on repositry which comes from `C:\Users\me\Documents\GitHub` and when I try to add files to existing repository which explained how I create them above I am getting `C:\Wamp64\MapApp is't a git repository` error again the command line changes working for Git folder. But I need to keep track of any changes on Wampserver folder

Comment: You can try and create a repo in the right folder and try to import it in GitHub Desktop

Comment: The one where it says it is not a got repository, but where you need to follow file changes

Comment: As I said I need to set Wamp www folder as my repository folder. I saw your answer at this post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22953060/can-i-combine-my-local-github-repository-with-wamp-localhost-folder` and it make more sence to me now

Comment: OK, got it now.

Comment: so you think I have to `be in the Github folder, but mention that the working tree is www`

Comment: Thanks a lost VonC, it was very helful